# Number format of axis - Google Gauge

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to change the number format of the axis on a google gauge. By default, the axis value is a whole number (e.g. 0, 120) but I would like to show a £ sign and format as currency (e.g. £0, £120). I have been able to change the format of the value shown at the bottom of the gauge using NumberFormat but cannot apply to the rest of the gauge.
The code for the basic gauge is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Spend', 80],
        ]);
        var options1 = {
          width: 500, height: 300
        };

        // change number format to £
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
        {pattern: '£###,###'});
        formatter.format(data1, 1);

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
        chart.draw(data1, options1);

  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart_div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I add a £ sign to the numbers on the outside of the gauge? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an array of strings to `majorTicks` to specify your own...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Spend', 80],
    ]);
    var options1 = {
      width: 500, height: 300,
      majorTicks: [
        '£0', '', '', '', '£100'
      ]
    };

    // change number format to £
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '£###,###'
    });
    formatter.format(data1, 1);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data1, options1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```